# Core Data - Get objects filtering data using the exact elements of an array

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, one-to-many, nsexpression

I have 3 entities: `object`, `object_tag` and `tag`, and i have to get just the objects matching an array of tags by its id, but not just a tag, but that exactly matches all the tags in the array. If the array has 3 tags, return all the objects that have these 3 tags and not more neither less.

The entities are like:

```
object
{
    id
    name
    -----
    tags <--->> object_tags
}

object_tag
{
    id
    id_object
    id_tag
    -----
    object <---> tags
    tag <---> objects
}

tag
{
    id
    name
    -----
    objects <--->> object_tags
}
```

Using predicates and/or expressions how can i get what i want?. I've tried many ways, but all I've gotten have been objects that include any of the tags in the array, but not all the tags at once.

**EDIT 1:**

Sorry, i forgot to clarify something about relationships. The entities `object` and `tag` points to the intermediate entity `object_tag`, that contains object-tag pairs.

Comment: I have problems to understand the relationships. Could you clarify which relationship points to which entity - alternatively you can post a screenshot of the Core Data graph view in Xcode.

Comment: What is the purpose of object_tag? You seem to be defining a lookup table that could instead be handled by Core Data automatically. In other words, objects and tags could just have a many-to-many relationship that Core Data manages. Unless there's a specific reason that you need object_tag outside of simply connecting objects to tags, eliminating that extra table should help you arrive at a simpler solution to your problem.

Comment: mmm, I had thought that. So, do you know how can I do it with/without the intermediate entity?. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: For a to-many relationship from object to tag this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084930/how-to-create-a-core-data-predicate-to-test-that-a-relation-contains-all-given-o/13086353#13086353. That solution can (probably) also be adapted to your more complicated situation with the intermediate entity.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR, but it didn't work for me. I'll try to delete the intermediate entity and see if that works. If you have another solution, i'll thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following predicate for the *object* entity *should* work:

```
NSArray *tagIds = @[ @1, @4, @7 ]; // Your set of tag ids
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(object_tags.@count == %d) AND (SUBQUERY(object_tags, $x, $x.tag.id IN %@).@count == %d)",
                      tagIds.count, tagIds, tagIds.count];
```

where `object_tags` is the to-many relationship from *object* to *object_tag*, and `tag` is the to-one relationship from *object_tag* to *tag*.

If you simplify your object model to a many-to-many relationship between `object` and `tag` (as suggested by David Ravetti in a comment), then the predicate would look like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(tags.@count == %d) AND (SUBQUERY(tags, $x, $x.id IN %@).@count == %d)",
                      tagIds.count, tagIds, tagIds.count];
```

If you only want to check that the object has all tags from the given array (but might have more tags), then you can simplify the query to

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tags, $x, $x.id IN %@).@count == %d",
                      tagIds, tagIds.count];
```

Comment: Thank you @MartinR. I deleted the intermediate entity and established relationships as many-to-many (as suggested by David Ravetti). Your predicate works but returns me duplicate objects. Why could this be?. Another question, how could i do to return the objects that match at least with objects of the array?

Comment: @ThXou: I have updated the answer for your second question. - I do not understand yet the problem with duplicate objects. A fetch request always returns an array of distinct objects.