# CoreData NSPredicate equals NSSet

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsset

I have an entity in CoreDate, let's call it A. This entity has a field, "dynamicBs", which is a 1:n relationship to entities of the type B. Thus, each entity of type A has a multitude of dynamicBs of type B.

What I need to do is check those entries where dynamicBs exactly matches a given NSSet. So far, I have tried:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dynamicBs = %@", dynamicBs]

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dynamicBs IN %@) AND (%@ IN dynamicBs)", dynamicBs, dynamicBs]
```

all at no avail. Both methods throw an error on the line

```
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

What might be the issue, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Core Data predicate to test that a relation contains all given objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084930/how-to-create-a-core-data-predicate-to-test-that-a-relation-contains-all-given-o)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've been looking but was unable to find it. I actually think that my wording is easier to index/find, so maybe it would make sense to leave my question nevertheless?

Comment: The question is not deleted if it is closed as a duplicate.