# NSPredicate to filter a to-many relationship with array of values

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I currently have these entities in my core data model: Post, Venue, Scene, and Feature. Scenes have an attribute named 'sceneId', and Features have an attribute names 'featureId'.

A Post has a 'to-one' relationship to a Venue, and a Venue has a 'to-many' relationship to a Scene and Feature.

What I want to accomplish is writing a NSPredicate to filter posts by an array of 'sceneId' attributes and/or an array of 'filterId' attributes.

I've tried :

```
var postPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "venue.scenes.sceneId IN %@", sceneIds)
```

But I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation
>   for predicate : (venue.scenes.sceneId IN {1})'

**Edit**

I tried querying the Venue entity with this predicate:

```
        var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(0 != SUBQUERY(scenes, $scene, $scene.sceneId IN %@).@count)", [2,3])
```

However I get values back if a Venues scenes.sceneId contains a 2 or 3. I want to get values back only when the scenes.sceneId associated with a venue contain 2 and 3.

**Update**

I found the answer finally on this post here: 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084930/how-to-create-a-core-data-predicate-to-test-that-a-relation-contains-all-given-o)