# NSPredicate to match all values of array in association

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a custom object that has an array of categories associated with it. I have an array of category IDs and I want to match all posts that have every category ID in the array (an AND filter, vs ANY).

Using the ANY keyword in NSPredicate, I can only match posts that have any single category ID in the array. Any other changes cause a crash.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY categories.categoryId in %@", categoryIdsToFilter]
```

This is a valid ANY search

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL categories.categoryId in %@", categoryIdsToFilter]
```

This fails.

My actual code uses strings but this works as an illustration. In terms of desired results, here is what I'm looking for

```
Post | Categories
A    | 1, 4, 5
B    | 1, 3, 6
C    | 2, 3, 6
```

If I pass in an array containing category IDs 1 and 3, I would expect Post B to be the only result. An array of 3 and 6 should return both Post B and C, and an array of only 1 will return Post A and B.

Comment: possibly you're looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084930/how-to-create-a-core-data-predicate-to-test-that-a-relation-contains-all-given-o

Comment: That _seems_ to have it, thanks. I find it difficult to search for existing questions when your issue is so specific.